# Kafka consumer client exception/error handling

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I would like to know about error/exception handling best-practices when working with native kafka consumer clients (Java, Python). Most of the error-handling questions on stack-overflow seem to be in the context of spring-boot's retry-handler. I would like to know if its possible to attach such error-handlers and retry-templates to non-spring managed consumers or when working with native consumer clients. I tried searching over stack-overflow and looks like there is no satisfactory answer. It would be helpful in general, if there is some general guidance on error-handling (when to transiently retry and recover) practices when working with native clients.

Comment: Obviously you can put a try-catch within your consumer poll loop (processing actions) or producer send calls, but I feel like you are asking about something else? Have you tried looking at the actual Spring source code, since they aren't doing anything differently?

Comment: Spring-kafka retry-handler is based on spring-retry. There are lot of non-spring based usage of native clients. Would be helpful if we have some documentation around various kinda transient failures that we could retry with backoff.

Comment: My point was that Spring is written in Java, and you are welcome to reinvent the wheel in any other framework, using that as a reference. The Kafka JavaDoc for Producer and Consumer classes mention what are transient errors, last I checked.

Comment: Im not sure how spring-kafka handles container errors - the errors thrown by the actual consumer and underlying thread. We can attach error-handler policy to the listener. Kafka java docs list the various kinda exceptions thrown by poll, commit, seek etc.. well, we can always look at implementation details but wanted to check basic exceptions that consumer container can retry and give up. Thanks.